# SELECT INTO that won't stop on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I ran a query a number of hours ago with a select into statement. I canceled the query, but it took awhile and my SQL Server client froze. The database that query was running on is now locked.

When I run `sp_who2`, I see these statistics:

```
Status: Runnable
BlkBy: "." <-- meaning blocked by nothing?
Command: Select into
CPU Time : 0
Disk IO : 0 
LastBatch : 12/30/2016 (today)
```

Is it that the query is still taking time to close? The status runnable apparently means its waiting for something -- is it waiting for more space allocation? I do not have sufficient privileges to kill the process and no one is around to help.

Could someone assist with this?

Comment: In SSMS, on the tab you're running sp_who2 from, is the spid in the tab information the same spid in the sp_who2 results?

Comment: The better bet is to run sp_whoisactive: http://whoisactive.com/

Comment: A running status means is it currently executing.  BlkBy with a period means it is not being blocked by anything so it will continue to run. SSMS freezing is usually a client issue and not from the server unless it is being launched from the server.  Agree with Erik, sp_whoisactive would show the actual sql being run.

Comment: When you execute sp_configure what is the Max Memory setting? Do you have other instances on this box? How many records were you inserting? What was the source of the SELECT INTO - another table on the same machine? A linked server? A flat file?

Comment: Also, what do you see in Resource Monitor (or ProcMon if you have downloaded SysInternals)?

Answer (score 2):

Well, what is the last wait type ?

If you cancelled the query, it has to rollback, so the cancel is not immediate.
For instance you want to insert into billions of rows in one statement (not sure it is a good idea, but let's imagine). It takes several hours to do it (and your disks are probably burning) and if you cancel it, it may also take hours to rollback everything that has been done.

Also, I often experienced similar issue when using a linked server to Oracle. Because the network was a bit sensitive and Oracle config a bit strict, long query using this linked server (more than 1 hour) were stuck : process wasn't there anymore on Oracle side, but still on SQLServer side, and this one was impossible to kill and was locking destination table. Only solution : restarting SQLServer service.

But that does not explain why SSMS is freezing...

Comment: If the database is on the same machine he ran the query and the max memory setting was left default, the OS and applications could be starved for memory with SQL Server using it all.